# C - Posix - cond_wait/signal

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, posix, init

In pure C, does `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal` / `pthread_cond_destroy`, `pthread_cond_init` set `errno` in case of error? Or do they just return a value != 0 ?

Comment: Did you look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal ?

Comment: Yes I did, and it doesn't specify, it just says it returns a value != then 0, now my question is,how could i do a errorcheck on it, while running it?
Should i do it like if(pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex) != 0) { perror....} ?

Comment: `int ret = pthread_cond_signal(...); switch (ret) { case 0: break; case EINVAL: /* handle the error */break;  /*other error cases for other functions*/}`.

Comment: Wouldn't this `if(pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex)) { handle error }; ` work as well? as in, would it still run the function, and if it returned 0, it would keep running, if it returned != 0 it would jump into the if statement?   @mch

Comment: yes, but in this case you only know that an error happened, not which one.

Comment: I just need to check if an error happens, not which kind of error, as it should `perror` and use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` to exit.

Answer (score 0):

From [pthreads man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html):

> Note that the pthreads functions do not set errno.

And documentation for specific functions says that on fail they `an error number is returned to indicate the error`. So you need just to check value returning by the function.

Comment: Yes, I realized this already, my question would be: `if(pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex)) { handle error }; ` would this run the wait function, and only handle the error if it returned != 0? @tsyvarev

Comment: Thank you, my question is if it would still run the function inside the if or not, or would just 'test' it. Sometimes I get this kind of derp moments.

Comment: Oh, yes, code within `if` clause is always compiled and executed as normal one. You, probably, confuse that with `assert()` macro, which condition is not compiled at all without debug enabled.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_cond_wait(3) man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait

> Upon successful completion, a value of zero shall be returned; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

pthread_cond_signal(3) man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal

> If successful, the pthread_cond_broadcast() and pthread_cond_signal() functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

pthread_cond_destroy(3) man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_destroy

> If successful, the pthread_cond_destroy() and pthread_cond_init() functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

pthread_cond_init(3) man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_init

> If successful, the pthread_cond_destroy() and pthread_cond_init() functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

This means that instead of putting the error number in the variable errno ,it is returned. You can use the `strerror` function to get the error string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int ret;
if( (ret = pthread_cond_init( {some args} ) ) != 0 )
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(ret));
```

Comment: Since I don't have to check the error type, I can just do it like `if(function){handle error}` ? Since the function still executes inside the if?

Comment: Yes, but if you are wondering if the the timeout occurs in the wait you need to check the error value. "Except in the case of [ETIMEDOUT], all these error checks shall act as if they were performed immediately at the beginning of processing for the function and shall cause an error return, in effect, prior to modifying the state of the mutex specified by mutex or the condition variable specified by cond."